# Why am I getting duplicates in a join between four tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, cartesian-product

tables and query are here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b6f35a/1/0

In it for each name i get its tags title, So it would be like this

```
name1: title1;
name2: title1;
name3: title1;
```

My problem is that i get double the tags

```
name1: title1, title1;
name2: title1, title1;
name3: title1;
```

What is the mistake i've made?

The entire problem comes for `tablx`

Sorry about the mess before, didn't know about sqlfiddle

Comment: Needs clarification. Are you saying that the _exact_ initial query with that _exact_ data is returning 8 rows instead of 4?

Comment: So instead of getting four result rows, you are getting eight? With the query shown this should only be possible if you have duplicates in one of the tables.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner and I are saying the same thing. To be more clear, assuming you've properly primary-keyed tables 1 & 3, only `tabl2` could have duplicates. You could prevent duplicates in that 'join' table by adding a unique key on pid + bid like: ```ALTER TABLE `tabl2` ADD UNIQUE (`pid`, `bid`);```

Comment: you have a typo  should be c.title and not b.title

Comment: @ThorstenKettner there is no duplicates at all to be duplicated.

Comment: @scaisEdge Corrected it now.

Comment: @jmorganmartin rewrote the actual query with the actual values i get.

Comment: what's the group by for at the end?

Comment: you have not  aggregation function so  you don't need  group by .. if you need  distinct result use distinct clause ..  and check for the real contend  of your data ..  the queri seems correct could be the data sample are not

Comment: @JamieD77 i get five of `title1` and only `name1` if removed it, I use it to group the main table rows with the id.

Comment: I just tested the updated query and it returns the desired result even without the group by, only 3 rows. What exactly do you what you want to achieve with that query?

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez that weird, i'll recheck the code again.

Comment: Run `SELECT pid, bid, COUNT(*) FROM tabl2 GROUP BY pid, bid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.  If you get result, that means you have duplicated records.

Comment: @AXAI How are you getting that output: `name1: title1, title1`? You must be doing some post-processing or using an aggregate function like `CONCAT`. Please paste the actual response to the query, not whatever you are doing. Also, double-check ```SELECT a.name, c.title``` (not `b.title`) as mentioned above.

Comment: [TEST](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/add3b/2) Just tested too. Returns desired result.

Comment: @AXAI To clarify, even though each name has multiple tags, you only want to view the one tag you are searching for? ```GROUP by a.id``` will ensure you never get more rows than you have names, and the `WHERE c.title in (title1)` will ensure that the tag returned for each row is the proper one (otherwise, it could be unpredictable). Again, your result seems impossible unless you have duplicate data in `tabl2` _and_ are doing some aggregate function that you haven't told us about. Adding a unique key as I mentioned above can prevent that from happening.

Comment: @jmorganmartin the original code has three `LEFT JOIN` rules in it, It is the reason of the problem, I've tried removing one of the three, the problem still occured, But tried removing two out of the three, the problem solved, tried with different couples and the problem solved, only one left join makes it work correctly, do i write it?

Comment: @AXAI You need as many joins as required to join your data. Paste the 3 `LEFT JOINS`.  Don't try to simplify the question too much, or else we won't be able to answer it, haha.

Comment: @jmorganmartin the x y z tables are just like tabl3

Comment: @AXAI It's still impossible to tell how you are getting that final output of `name1: title1, title1`. That's not coming straight from SQL. Can you dump the rows output from the query and not whatever you are dumping?

Comment: @AXAI Updated SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03205d/1  Still not able to recreate.

Comment: @jmorganmartin I've found which left join actually makes the problem, And i made one table form wrong, the problem LEFT JOIN comes from a `rating` table, Will rewrite it and check it now.

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez added  the actual tables and query link showing the problem as meant.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner added a link with sqlfiddle to show the problem.

Comment: @scaisEdge it seems that it was another table making the problem, just added an sqlfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join with X table is returning the 4th row. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b6f35a/6, which draws the same `title1` value in from the tags table, which is then aggregated into the final response with `GROUP_CONCAT()`

A solution if you need to join both these tables in one query but only want the `title1` one time is to remove the `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregator: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b6f35a/7

```
    SELECT a.name, x.rate, c.title
    FROM tabl1 a 
    LEFT JOIN tablx x ON x.pid = a.id 
    INNER JOIN tabl2 b ON a.id = b.pid 
    INNER JOIN tabl3 c ON c.id = b.bid 
    WHERE c.title IN ('title1') 
    GROUP BY a.id
```

In your case, it might be more useful to have an aggregator on the rate column for x table, like so: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b6f35a/9

```
    SELECT a.name, x.rate, c.title, SUM(x.rate) AS rate_sum
    FROM tabl1 a 
    LEFT JOIN tablx x ON x.pid = a.id 
    INNER JOIN tabl2 b ON a.id = b.pid 
    INNER JOIN tabl3 c ON c.id = b.bid 
    WHERE c.title IN ('title1') 
    GROUP BY a.id
```

If you just want to *count* the number of distinct tags in this situation, you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b6f35a/15:

```
    SELECT a.name, b.id as bid, c.title, x.id as xid, x.rate, c.title, SUM(x.rate) AS rate_sum, COUNT(DISTINCT c.title) as title_count
    FROM tabl1 a 
    LEFT JOIN tablx x ON x.pid = a.id 
    INNER JOIN tabl2 b ON a.id = b.pid 
    INNER JOIN tabl3 c ON c.id = b.bid 
    WHERE c.title IN ('title1') 
    GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: There is no possible way to count `c.title` at all while keeping everything as it is?

Answer (score 0):

If everything in the posted question is correct, you aren't doing anything wrong.

See this sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03205d/1

Comment: @AXAI, The join with X table is returning the 4th row. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b6f35a/6

Comment: The only solution if you need to join both these tables in one query is to remove the `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregator: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b6f35a/7

Comment: @AXAI In your case, it might be more useful to have an aggretator on the `rate` column for x table, like so: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b6f35a/9